# C# - How to access config values in Project1 from Project2? Project2 is referenced in main Project1

Tags: c#

Project1 is the MainProject, so I want to do all work on Project1's app.config.
I have a collection in Project1 config which I want to access from Project2.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: does each project not have its own app.config file?

Comment: but why ? can't you copy over the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This is not advisable because you will have the other project rely on Project 1's configuration.

If you do want to do it you can do something like this:

```
  //Reference Project 1 in Project 2 then create a public class 
 // create a public property that stores configuration you want.
 // read the configuration with the ConfigurationManager  



 Public Class Datalayer

 Public connetionString = 
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection").ConnectionString
```

Now you can access that property in the referenced project. Again this is not ideal and i didn't test it.